# How can I connect my phongap app with the database in the webserver

Tags: php, android, cordova, server

I'm new to creating mobile apps using phonegap. So I'm trying to create a small form and when the user click submit the data should go to the online server which I created in ServersFree.com

So I was going to put the php file only to the file manager and access it from html file which I'm going to put to my phone after I create the apk file using build phonegap. is it the correct way to do it?

```
<?php
$servername = "hin123.bugs3.com";
$username = "u137593186";
$password = "ulsdjj29822";
$dbname = "u137593186_user";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);}

$name = $_POST['Name'];
$age = $_POST['Age'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (name, age, username, password)
VALUES ('$name', '$age','$username','$password')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

this is my html file

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/register.css" />

<title>Registration</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form id='register' action='insert.php' method='POST'>
        <fieldset >
        <legend>Register</legend>

        <form action="" method="post">
        <label>Name :</label>
        <br></br>
        <input id="Name" name="Name" type="text">
        <br></br>
        <label>Age :</label>
        <br></br>
        <input id="Age" name="Age" type="text">
        <br></br>
        <label>UserName :</label>
        <br></br>
        <input id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text">
        <br></br>
        <label>Password :</label>
        <br></br>
        <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" type="password">
        <br></br>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        <br></br>

        <span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: action="insert.php" . change it  based on your file location , `no need localhost`.....

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to change url OR
if your both files in same folder then just use

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
```

It will work for both local and live server.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
```